# Cannot complete GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to create a form to collect email addresses. The email address POSTs to /dreamjob.

When I try to access the list on /emails no error shows up but the page does not load & times out. I cannot figure out the issue. How would I change my code to correct this? Thank you!

```
router.post("/dreamjob", function(req, res){

    //Create Email
    Email.create(req.body.email, function(err, newEmail){
        if(err){
            res.render("station.ejs");
        } else {
            newEmail.save();
            console.log(req.body.email)
        }
    });
});


//All Emails: 
    router.get("/emails", function(req, res){
    Email.find, function(err, email){
        if (err){
        console.log("ERROR!");
         } else { 
    res.render("emails", {Email: email});
    }
    }
    });
```

Model:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var emailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   email: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Email", emailSchema);
```

Comment: You drop the request if there is a error, did you check the console? Also, shouldn't it be `res.render('emails.ejs', {Email: email})`?

Comment: there is a syntax error on your code... is it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an email, you're only responding to the request in case of error, try something like this:

```
 Email.create(req.body.email, function(err, newEmail){
    if(err){
        res.render("station.ejs");
    } else {
        newEmail.save();
        console.log(req.body.email);
        res.send(200); // reply to the http request here
    }
});
```